# Sampling and reconstruction frequency

Tags: fourier-analysis

> For a sinusoid frequency of $1200$Hz and a sampling frequency of $2000$Hz and a reconstruction frequency of $2000$Hz and $3000$Hz, what frequency will the sinusoid be after the reconstruction?

#### Progress

I divided $1200/2000$ for $f/f_s$ but am unsure of how to apply the reconstruction frequency to get the answer. ... $1200/2000 \cdot 2\pi = 1.6\pi$ and for the reconstruction frequency $2\pi/3000$, what would I do to get the end result?

Comment: You need to show some work and explain where you have gotten stuck. I'm a nice guy, but I don't come here to do your homework for you. You can see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) post about asking homework questions.

Comment: i divided 1200/2000 for f/fs but am unsure of how to apply the reconstruction freq to get the answer

Comment: Once you sample the signal, your units are radians per sample, right? For a given reconstruction frequency, each sample is going to separated by a certain amount of time. Can you see how to combine these two to get back to radians per second (or Hertz per second if those are the units you want to use).

Comment: so 1200/2000 * 2pi = 1.6pi and for the reconstruction freq 2pi/3000, what would I do to get the end result

Comment: please sir, please

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the units around, it makes it much easier. If you sample at $f_s$, then every $1/f_s$ seconds a sample is recorded. If the sinusoid you are sampling has a frequency of $2\pi f_0$ (rad/s) and you sample it as $f_s$, then we get

$$
2\pi f_0 \mathrm{(rad/s)} \cdot { {1} \over {f_s} } \mathrm{(s/sample)} = 2\pi { {f_0} \over {f_s} } \mathrm{(rad/sample)}
$$

If you reconstruct with a frequency of $f_r$, then every sample will be treated as if it is $1/f_r$ seconds apart, which means there will be $f_r$ samples per second. Thus, the reconstructed frequency will be

$$
2\pi { {f_0} \over {f_s} } \mathrm{(rad/sample)} \cdot f_r \mathrm{ (samples/s) } = 2\pi f_0 { {f_r} \over {f_s} } \mathrm{(rad/sample)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The point of this exercise seems to be that your sampling frequency falls 400Hz short of the Nyquist rate of 2400Hz. Thus your sampled signal will be indistinguishable from a sine wave at 800Hz=(2000Hz-400Hz)/2. You should be able to work out the corresponding amplitudes and pahse shifts, if any.